# Android : Toast is displayed after function executed, expecting it to show before

Tags: android, menu, toast

Might be a silly problem, or something that is way above my current java knowledge. Either way, I'm stuck so hopefully someone can assist.

I have an application with a menu and a few items. One of these items is meant to update a music playlist (the application is essentially a SSH remote controller for Audacious).
Since the playlist update can take a little while depending on its size, I am intending to display a toast upon the item click, and another after it was updated.

Problem is, upon clicking on that item, the main thread hangs (calls a function that in turn calls a  DoInBackground function, and updates the main activity fields upon receiving the data -- I couldn't make everything in background), and both toasts are displayed at the end.
So the app seems to be frozen for a few seconds.

The menu code is below. Is there a way to make that toast appears upon clicking the item ? 
If more code is necessary I will post it. (the called functions maybe)

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    final Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.Settings:
            vib.vibrate(50);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.Help:
            vib.vibrate(50);
            HelpWindow();
            break;

        case R.id.Quit:
            vib.vibrate(50);
            SshCommands.quit quit = new SshCommands.quit();
            quit.execute();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            exit(0);

        case R.id.refreshPlaylist:
            vib.vibrate(50);

            if (session != null && session.isConnected()) {
                SshCommands.ToastHandler message = new SshCommands.ToastHandler(getApplicationContext());
                message.showToast("Downloading playlist. Please wait.");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    this.refreshPlaylist();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else {
                SshCommands.ToastHandler message = new SshCommands.ToastHandler(getApplicationContext());
                message.showToast("Not connected.");
            }

            break;
```

Here is the code for the called function :

```
   public void refreshPlaylist() {

    if (session != null) {


        try {
            session.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.toString().contains("already connected")) {

                SshCommands.getPlaylist getplaylist = new SshCommands.getPlaylist();

                SshCommands.loadPlaylist loadplaylist = new SshCommands.loadPlaylist();

                try {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        getplaylist.execute();

                        String currentpl;

                        while (getplaylist.currentplaylist == null) {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                        currentpl = getplaylist.currentplaylist;

                        playlist.setText("Playlist: " + currentpl);

                        loadplaylist.execute();

                        pl = loadplaylist.songs;
                        while (pl.isEmpty()) {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            pl = loadplaylist.songs;
                        }

                        createListview();

                        SshCommands.TrackName song = new SshCommands.TrackName();
                        song.execute();
                        o = 0;
                        int i = 0;
                        try {
                            while (i < 30 && song.trackName == null) {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                                i = i + 1;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (song.trackName != null) {
                            o = song.trackName;
                        }
                        if (!(o == 0)) {
                            o = o - 1;
                            scrollToPosition();
                        } else {
                            toast();
                        }

                        SshCommands.ToastHandler message1 = new SshCommands.ToastHandler(this);
                        message1.showToast("Playlist downloaded.");

} else {
etc.
//just requests the write permissions on the storage
```

Comment: Can you check if it's working with Toast.makeText ?

Comment: yes, tested as well, same result. The SshCommands thing regroup all the control functions, was "cleaner" that way. The toast works properly when called like that elsewhere.

Comment: Try removing Thread.Sleep and post the code of refreshPlaylist

Comment: @Jackson_DKMG Please show the `refreshPlaylist()` method.

Comment: ok I just posted that code. Removing the sleep did not help (its presence not useful anyway).

Comment: This called function in turn calls async functions, gathers the data (playlist name and contents, current track), then displays them in the appropriate text and listview fields. I am guessing that the issue is the code executing on the main thread, but I'm unclear on how to move it to the background and still be able to update these fields.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, should never use Thread.sleep() on the main thread. It will freeze your app for the specified time.
The reason you see both toasts at the end is that they are actually posted on to your app's main thread queue, which is freezed by Thread.sleep().

The correct way to do it is to use postDelayed().

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, there are sleeps on the main thread to allow time for the SSH commands to provide their output. I should probably redo the application completely. I'll look into the postDelayed() thing.